# Building a DNA sequence generator

Tags: python, random, generator, bioinformatics, dna-sequence

I'm just starting to learn python in a bioinformatics research lab. My first project was to generate a program that can spit out various DNA sequences with parameters of length and number of copies. The sequences would then need to be output in FASTA format.

For those unfamiliar a DNA sequence can be made up of four "letters": A,G,C,T. 
 Example DNA sequence: ACGTTCCGTACGTACTCT

I am really new to this all and I would like some advice on how to go about this and how to learn python in general (rely on tutorials, do random projects, etc).

I am currently using someone else's program for my DNA sequence project and then I will go through line by line to see what's being done.

The first error I encountered when copying over the code was this:

```
    >>> import random
    >>> import sys
    >>> def simulate_sequence (length) :
        dna = ['A','G','C','T']
        sequence = ''
        for i in range (length) :
            sequence += random.choice (dna)
        return sequence

    >>> setsize = int (sys.argv[1])
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<pyshell#10>", line 1, in <module>
        setsize = int (sys.argv[1])
    IndexError: list index out of range
    >>>
```

Thank you.

Comment: You need to call this code with a CLI argument specifying the length of the sequence.

Comment: Unfortunately there’s simply not much sense with copying code without a rudimentary understanding of the basics. I advise you to pick up a book *first* before diving in.

Comment: start with the official tutorial, it contains everything you need to know! http://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/index.html

Comment: I don't know who wrote the original code, but the `simulate_sequence` function is nothing more than `''.join(random.choice('AGCT') for _ in range(length))`.

Comment: thank you everyone. i went through a tutorial by thenewboston for python. I have a basis of whats going on, but i have a ton to practice...i think i will continue reading python books while working on projects in my lab.

Comment: what everyone is trying to say, I believe is : to run the program:type python filename.py 100 or any othe number you like :-)

Answer (score 1):

I use biopython for this:

```
def random_seq(N=180):
    return Seq("".join(random.choice("ATCG") for _ in range(N)))
```

Answer (score 0):

`sys.argv` is a list of the arguments passed to your program.

For instance this program (called `amt.py`):

```
import sys
print (sys.argv)
```

will behave like this:

```
$ ./amt.py
['./amt.py']
$ ./amt.py 1
['./amt.py', '1']
$ ./amt.py 1 abc
['./amt.py', '1', 'abc']
$ ./amt.py 1 abc 33
['./amt.py', '1', 'abc', '33']
```

The problem with your code is that it is expecting `sys.argv` to have an item at index 1, but you haven't given it any command line arguments. So it tries to go to a non-existent location in the list.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would recommend [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00B7RE628).

The error comes from the fact that this program was made to be run from the command line, not for the interpreter. `sys.argv[1]` gets the 1st command line argument (well, technically the 2nd because the first is the name of the program). In the interpreter you cannot specify arguments. Just paste it into a text editor and run it from the command line like: DNA.py 100

Answer (score 0):

```
dna = ['A','G','C','T']
def generateDNA(N):
   result= [random.choice(dna) for i in np.arange(N)]
   return("".join(result))

print(generateDNA(100))
```

output:

TTCGCGGACGGTTCATCAGCCCTAGCCGGTTAAGAACTATCGAGCCACCCTAAGAACGGTCCATATTTGGAGTGTTACAACTTTGGATCTTCTACGTTGC